# javascript error: Disallowed method "elementsFromPoint" on ShadowRoot on doing mouse hover using Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework, shadow-dom, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to mouse hover on some element using Robot Framework's keyword **Mouse Over** but I get error as "**javascript error: Disallowed method "elementsFromPoint" on ShadowRoot.**". Other Keyword like Click Element is working for the same element. But when I try to mouse hover, it throws me the above error. I am not sure how to resolve this error.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at [tour] and [MCVE]

Comment: shadowRoot itself is not a DOM Element. It is a container for elements. execute ``elementsFromPoint`` on an actual DOM Element

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman My application is salesforce, and problem is there is no shadow-root DOM in the entire DOM. But the error says ShadowRoot. Do you know when javascript throws such error?

Comment: Nope, I don't know the Salesforce (LWC Components) I think StackOverflow has a specific tag for them; otherwise try Twitter and ask where the Salesforce Web Component gurus are.

Answer (score 1):

This just appeared for me as well due to some recent update from SalesForce and their tooltips. What I would recommend is to wrap the action in a Try/Catch and then try the alternate approach below.

What I did was to get the parent of the element - which is likely some descriptive text - click the parent to give it the focus, and use sendkeys TAB to activate the Tooltip.

Since this is wrapped in a Try / Catch, if SalesForce chooses to roll back this change, there will be no further maintenance required.

BY the way I tried a bunch of JavaScript solutions  arguments[0].focus()
arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover')
and I could not get any to work.

Also you may find as I have that running tests on a headless Chrome browser on Linux renders the Action mouse and click actions useless.

```
> Blockquote 

       try {
            actions.moveToElement(element, 5, 5).perform();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //Alternate to activate an 'i' help hover 
            WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
            click(parent);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I tried the same approach as you have told. I set focus on the parent element and then clicked on Tab key. It worked.  I thought this is Chrome issue but as you said this is due to some recent update from SalesForce and their tooltips.

Comment: Thanks Ankita. I removed the Tab off as it was did not always work in further testing and appeared redundant. I am also looking into getting the activeElement to see if an alternate Tab/Shift-Tab approach to pop the Help text might be viable. It was my first automation workaround 20 years ago.

Comment: I could really use some Up Arrows for my meager Reputation. :)

Comment: @ DarkArtsWizard There is one issue that I am facing again. I am able to mouse hover in debug mode but it is not working when I run it. I tried adding some wait and tried slowing down selenium speed. But it is not working. I also tried mouse hovering using javascript. That also did not work. I will try to explore more. If you come across some other solution, please let me know.

Comment: @ DarkArtsWizard Glad to hear that you have such a rich experience into automation.

Comment: Then follow me on Twitter. I also admin the "Advance Test Automation" group on FB with 9000+ members.

Comment: Sure. I'll post any other hover solutions I can work out. 
This one is just a workaround. From some testing this AM there are other Salesforce pages that it does not work quite as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2333#issuecomment-848378833 the workaround is to downgrade ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 0):

For ChromeDriver 90 and newer, you can use `dispatchEvent()` like following.

```
var javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {'bubbles': true }));", element);
```

Comment: It can also be used for click event. (`bubbles` is required for my case.)

`javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {'bubbles': true }));", element);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while clicking on a Salesforce button.
JavaScript workaround basesed on nobyk's solution worked so far.

```
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].focus(); arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was introduced from chrome driver version 90.
Here is a defect tracking this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3791

Actions class methods like moveToElement,dbclick etc seems to be broken from chrome driver version 90. Especially when the elements are in shadow DOM parents.

I recommend downgrading to chrome browser 89 with chromium 89(to prevent auto update)
[Chromium 89.0.4350.6](https://chromium.cypress.io/win64/dev/89.0.4350.6)
[chromedriver 89](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=89.0.4389.23/)